# make VERBOSE=1 documentation?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I thought I knew what `make VERBOSE=1` is and what it does.

I can see that it's conspicuously absent from https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html .

Where is the GNU Make command-line variable definition `VERBOSE=1` documented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it's "conspicuously absent" from the GNU make documentation, is that the variable `VERBOSE` has zero special meaning to make at all.

It may be that SOME makefiles will do something interesting with `VERBOSE`, but that's because that specific makefile is written to treat that variable specially.  Other makefiles will ignore it, or it has some other meaning than what you think it does.

For example, makefiles that are created by CMake will behave specially when you set the `VERBOSE` variable, but makefiles that are created by automake don't pay any attention to it at all.  In automake makefiles, you use `V=1` not `VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: So, you shouldn't look in the GNU make documentation for how `VERBOSE` is treated; instead you need to look in the documentation for the makefiles you're working with.